# Включение функции при подгрузе контента ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть `<script class="script" type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>`
на главной странице, но так функция не вызвается, и в один из блоков этой страницы мне необходимо подгружать контент и выполнять определенный js код, если подгружать эту строку `<script class="script" type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>` в подгружаемый контент , то оно  накладывается и получается, что код выполняется сначала 1 раз , потом 2 , потом 3 и тд. Как можно решать эту проблему?

Comment: **не** подгружать эту строку ... в подгружаемый контент

Comment: ну так функцию не видит

Comment: что значат эти слова?

Comment: ну то и значит, что в main js есть функция,но она не вызывается по клику на элемент в подгруженном контенте

Comment: Это очень плохо. Значит Вы неправильно это делаете.

Comment: Попробуй поставить эту строку в конец `body` перед `</body>`

Comment: код в студию!)  - желательно функцию, ее вызов . и html